# GeoFire Android : GeoQuery is only showing the nearest , not all nearby users

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am making an app where users can find all nearby users of the app . Location data of All users are stored like this :[image: Firebase Realtime Database Using GeoFire]

If I use that code code :

```
    ...
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
    GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
    GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(Double.parseDouble(userData.getString("latitude","")),Double.parseDouble(userData.getString("longitude",""))), radius);
    geoQuery.removeAllListeners();
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
            arrayListUserIds.add(key);
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
```

It only gives the nearest one , not all the nearby users .

I searched enough on the internet but got no clue.

Comment: Are you sure that all your users are within the radius?

Comment: Yes . To be sure I have increased radius to 10 km . But results were same .

Comment: Have you also tried to use different location coordinates because all your locations have the the approximate exact same coordinates?

Comment: I have tried different locations too . Is there any problem if I use exact same location coordinates ?

Comment: If you'll to see them on map, you'll only see one because the orher are beneath it, right?

Comment: I am populating the keys in a listview not not marking their position on map .

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another event listener:

```
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryDataEventListener(new GeoQueryDataEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataEntered(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, GeoLocation location) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        arrayListUserIds.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    }
                }
                ...
```